# Use pulseaudio for remote ssh connection

Tags: macos, ssh, audio, pulse-audio

I am trying to stream pulseaudio sound output over the cloud instance. In my previous question I could not get paprefs to work on Mac OS but it turned out it does not matter as I can set everything by editing `default.pa`. So I set up both the server and the client and tested over the local network (same wifi) by connecting to another Ubuntu machine. I used `pulseaudio zeroconf discover` and `pulseaudio zeroconf publish` for this. Everything works. I could discover and select the audio device from my client machine. 
Then I tried the same steps for the remote Oracle cloud instance. However this time, nothing is detected so I cannot select anything. I assume I should be at least select the "dummy speaker" and "dump microphone" from the client but nothing is detected. I suspect this is due to `pulseaudio zeroconf` modules only work for local network? I am not too sure about this. I tried to follow this post [Remote PulseAudio Setup](https://superuser.com/questions/1403076/remote-pulseaudio-setup) by selecting the server still does not work. I am not too sure what it meant by "enabled network access to global sound devices" so I have not done that. Do I need to set up a tunnel between two machines? 
`Edit` I tried to use tunnel by adding `load-module module-tunnel-sink-new server=192.168.0.1 sink_name=Remote channels=2 rate=44100`  to default.pa file. But it did not work. The module does not load. Upon closer inspection, the module loads for a brief instant and the disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zeroconf service discovery (more commonly known as DNS-SD/Avahi/Bonjour) typically uses link-local multicast packets (mDNS), which is limited to the current subnet only.

(Well, it technically *is* possible to add DNS-SD service discovery information to your standard DNS domain, and Avahi on Linux does support that, but it's a *very* rarely used feature and it won't be automatic – it takes a bit of manual setup, and in your case not worth the effort.)

To use PulseAudio across different networks you'll need to manually specify the PA server's address on the client. (Like with X11, the 'client' would be your Oracle Cloud instance, and the 'server' is your local macOS system.)

First the Pulse server must be accessible from the client – normally you would use SSH's "remote" tunnel for this: `ssh -R 4318:localhost:4317 oraclevm`.

Next you can either load `module-tunnel-(source,sink)(-new)` on the client (Oracle) system to connect specific inputs or outputs, similar to how it'd happen with Zeroconf, or completely redirect libpulse to connect straight to your local PulseAudio server (by setting `PULSE_SERVER=` in the environment).

- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-tunnel-sinksource
- http://hansekbrand.se/code/NetworkedAudio.html

Note however that PulseAudio remote connections using `native-protocol` will transmit raw PCM audio, which is going to require a lot of bandwidth.

You should instead try Xpra, which provides improved X11 forwarding over WAN and automatically configures audio as well (using PulseAudio).

Comment: Is there any reason for using the port 4318 and 4317?

Comment: 4317 is the default port that pulseaudio's native-tcp listens on, and 4318 is just a random port I selected so that the tunnel listener won't conflict with pulseaudio listener just in case native-tcp was enabled in the VM as well.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Network/ In the documentation it says the port number is 4713. So I am confused.

Comment: Ah, I guess I mistyped it then?

Comment: I confirmed that the number is 4713 by using lsof on the open ports. To be honest, at this point of time I still could not make the SSH connect work. Again the tunnel works on local. But I believe you detailed explanation deserves to be the answer.