# no soundcards found...for pulseaudio tunneling

Tags: linux, ssh, microphone, pulse-audio

Refers to my previous question
[Use pulseaudio for remote ssh connection](https://superuser.com/questions/1707633/use-pulseaudio-for-remote-ssh-connection) . I have finally got the tunnel established between my Mac OS and the Oracle instance. I input the wrong parameter in the ssh reverse tunnel and that was the reason why it does not work before. I got the audio forwarding working, so the instance can play any sound file and I will hear it on my Mac. 
However, the reverse is not working. I cannot record using my microphone on Mac OS. I tried to enable the loopback module mentioned in this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36286864/pulseaudio-microphone-over-network). It did not fix the problem. I tried to record using `arecord --device=pulse test.wav` and `arecord --device=default test.wav-` both did not make a difference. I tried `arecord -l` it says `arecord: device_list:276: no soundcards found...` 
The output of `pacmd list-sources`:

```
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <Romote.monitor>
    driver: <module-tunnel-sink-new.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: RUNNING
    suspend cause: (none)
...
```

Do I need additional steps?

Comment: Do parec/paplay work, and do you have the pulseaudio module for ALSA installed?

Comment: Paplay never worked for me, but parec works. The documentation says "You should (almost) never need to load this module manually. ", but I will try to enable it and see what happens

Comment: I mean the module in ALSA that adds the virtual 'pulse' devices, not the other way around. (For example, in Arch that's installed separately from pulseaudio itself, via /etc/alsa/conf.d/99-pulseaudio-default.conf.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry I have made a stupid mistake. I did not enable `load-module module-tunnel-source-new server` in the `default.pa` file. After enabling it, the microphone works fine...